# What does 'arra' mean?

Tags: meaning

I read it in a book but can't remember what topic now.  Google just brings up a list of place names, but I'm sure it's not that. It's not in my Oxford dictionary either and I'm fairly sure it's not an abbreviation.

Comment: So if you don't remember the topic and someone points out the meaning of a word that looks similar to *arra* how will you know if that's the one? I'm curious.

Comment: There are several answers below. Without the context of the word it's pretty difficult to judge which is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might you be thinking of [arras](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_arras_mean)?

rich tapestry; tapestry weave; a wall hanging, as a tapestry or similar object; (Theater) a curtain suspended loosely across a stage and used as a backdrop or part of a stage setting.
Origin: 1375–1425; late Middle English.

Comment: Could be this, Susan, as I've read a few books on that period of English history.

Answer (score 3):

It is an interjection in **[Hiberno-English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English)**.

[image]

And the citation is from a book called "Testimony of an Irish Slave Girl" by Kate McCafferty:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The online Oxford English Dictionary has an entry for *arrha*, defined as:

> Earnest-money, a part of the purchase-money given to ratify a
>   contract; *figuratively*,  a pledge.

The first citation is from 1574.

Answer (score 0):

It is the way they pronounce 'arrow' in Norfolk. Perhaps it's from the writings of Norfolk humourist, Sidney Grapes!